# Is it possible to retrieve the port where a Java EE application is deployed

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

Is it possible to know in my Java code the port where a Java EE application has been deployed?

Is it possible to do a not container specific solution?

Thanks a lot in advance.

**Edit**: It whould be nice if this is discovered in a `ServletContextListener` since it will be done on startup.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a handle of the `HttpServletRequest`, then you can get it by [`ServletRequest#getServerPort()`](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getServerPort%28%29) (the port which the client used) and/or [`ServletRequest#getLocalPort()`](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getLocalPort%28%29) (the port which the server *actually* uses --which might not be visible for the client due to router/proxy), depending on which port exactly you'd like to know about.

Comment: The problem is that I need it for something that i'm doing on deployment time. If it was in a servlet that whould be a good idea.

Comment: Oh, then you indeed have a problem. Either hardcode/configure it externally (not container specific), or make use of JMX (container specific though).

Comment: Yup, in the end JMX had to be used.

Thanks a lot